# Google maps api get results all the time

Tags: google-maps

I have a small problem with my Google Maps API and I would appreciate a little help.

I make a request for a place ( LAT ,LONG ) to google to give me the related restaurants ( for example a distance of 500 meters).
Everything is fine with places in crowded areas ( a big city like paris)

My problem is how to determine a solution to request to google the right distance to give me the nearest places for a not so crowded with places .

I better example:
 - I request the LAT LONG of an area that on an area of 500m has no restaurant but it has on the 2km area.
 - If a make the request with 50km area the results are not good as long as I can't control the order google gave me back.
 - How can I find the minimal distance to request so I get the best results for my application

Thank you and Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You would need to compute the distance from user's location to each result and then reorder the results to pick the closest one/s. I believe [you can re-order the results](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchResults) (I'm no lawyer but see [ToS 10.1.1.d](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html), usual disclaimer applies) from the Places API as long as you make it clear (to your users) that you've don it ;)